# Pulling specific string with lxml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I have the html:

```
<div title="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-template="
<div class=&quot;tooltip infowin-tooltip&quot; role=&quot;tooltip&quot;>
<div class=&quot;tooltip-arrow&quot;>
<div class=&quot;tooltip-arrow-inner&quot;>
</div>
</div>
<div class=&quot;tooltip-inner&quot; style=&quot;text-align: left&quot;>
</div>
</div>"
 data-html="true" data-placement="top" data-container=".snippet-container" class="font-160 line-110 text-default text-light" data-original-title="HOUSTON [US]">
<ahref="/en/ais/details/ports/919" class="no-underline group-ib color-inherit">USHOU</a>
</div>
```

I want to pull "HOUSTON [US]" from it using `lxml`. With `BeautifulSoup` I could do

`soup.find("div", class_='font-160 line-110')["title"]`

is there anything similar in `lxml`? I tried

```
parsed_body.xpath('.//div[@class="font-160 line-110 text-default text-light")["title"]')[0].text
```

But this returns blank.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the XPath:

```
//div[@class="font-160 line-110 text-default text-light"]/@data-original-title
```

in XPath, square brackets represent predicates. Predicates filter *which* nodes are returned without affecting *what* is returned. i.e. so your example would return the `div` element itself.

To get the value of an attribute you need to use a path separator (`/`) followed by an `@` symbol, and the attribute name.

Comment: `('//div/@data-original-title')` this seems to work for the copy and pasted string above, however when parsing the html it doesn't. Which is strange because `('//div/@data-placement')` returns `['top']` as when parsing the html. Why would this be?

Comment: is there more than one `div` with a `data-original-title` attribute in your full HTML?

Comment: yes, there are a few. Interestingly enough if I do `('//@title')[2]` it finds the string I'm looking for. Is there a reason that it's not finding `data-original-title`?

Comment: can you share your full HTML please?

Comment: What's the best way to do that?

Comment: fair warning! it's really long http://pastebin.com/SVQxKcBC, look at line 454 for example of sample code

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `//div/@title[0]` which pulls the desired text.